# Is there a ui-component for vaadin that I can use for text highlighting?

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

I am new to Javascript and Vaadin. I am looking for a text component that allows highlighting and annotation. This is what I have in mind.

I want to display a couple of paragraphs on my web-page and then the user should be able to select certain sections of text and add a highlight. When the user clicks on the highlighted section, I want to show a context-menu with some operations.

Is there a vaadin component or some other javascript component I can use or modify to achieve what I am looking for?

If there do not exist any components, can you suggest the steps that I need to do to create such a component.

Comment: have you checked the addons?  https://vaadin.com/directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

Rich text area: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.richtextarea.html

Context menu: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/69

I made a quick demo project with a rich text area & a context text area.

In the bottom text area I have right clicked & you can see a context menu appears with "Insert" & "Clean". This is customisable & just needs some css styles.

[image]

You could use a rich text area to edit your text, similar to wikipedia? Maybe by having an edit tab or an edit option in your context menu?

[image]

Or you could edit the text in a pop up panel, activated on a double click? Might look cool!

See http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/popup-view
(You can put any layout with components on this)

Or you could put your text in a read only text area & could even use the context menu to change the background color of your highlighted text?

I'll keep looking...